# Cannot find element for a popup chart that opens in the same page after clicking a button using selenium package in python. NoSuchElementException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://indexes.morningstar.com/our-indexes/fixed-income/F000011BSH") 
searchfor = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sal-components-performance"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')

## This opens the popup chart. Works fine
searchfor.click()

## This is the xpath of the button in that popup chart called "MAX". This throws NoElementFound error
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/button[12]').click()
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/button[12]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

How to click the buttons in that popup chart window that appears on the same page? I think the element of the popup chart window is not found because it uses the source code of the first page without the popup window code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use webdriver wait and switch to iframe:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://indexes.morningstar.com/our-indexes/fixed-income/F000011BSH")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Show Interactive Chart")]/..').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,
                                                                        '//iframe')))





## This is the xpath of the button in that popup chart called "MAX". This throws NoElementFound error
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
    '/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/button[12]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still cannot find the element in the popup chart. On that page, in the left corner of a static chart, you can see a button "Show Interactive Chart". I'm clicking that first which opens a popup chart on that same page using selenium but cannot click the buttons in the popup chart because those buttons cannot be found by selenium. When inspected the source code, the popup chart code appears only after clicking that button but selenium uses the code before clicking the button. Not sure how to detect the elements of the popup chart.

Comment: @KaushikGanesan thanks for that infromation , updated the answer use the updated informtaion